# How do I set a maximum line length for Rails Slim HTML email templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, slim-lang

I'm using `Slim` as the templating language for my HTML email. When pretty mode is turned off in production, it puts all the HTML on one line. When the emails go through `Sendgrid`, a line break is introduced at the 998th character, breaking the HTML. `Sendgrid` does this to comply with the email RFC.

How can I turn pretty mode off while rendering the email, tell `Slim` to respect the maximum line length, or introduce a hard line break?

Comment: I know your question said you wanted to leave pretty mode off, but I think turning it on in production is a better solution than inserting line breaks randomly.

`Slim::Engine.set_default_options :pretty => true`

Comment: Maybe if I could turn it on just for the HTML emails, not globally.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a few of these

```
= "\r\n"
```

throughout the email template solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `data-force-encoding="✓"` attribute to the `body` tag. That will make Rails to send email as quoted printable (trick is to use UTF8 char in fact). See: https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/123